# How do I automatically hide the Protected View infobar in Adobe Reader?

Tags: security, pdf, adobe-reader, protected-mode

I've configured Adobe Reader XI to use Protected Mode for all files in Preferences -> Security (Enhanced), but this pops up a yellow "Protected View" infobar every time I open a PDF, even if I'm opening the same PDF again.  The infobar says:

"Protected View: This file originated from a potentially unsafe location, and most features have been disabled to avoid potential security risks. [Enable All Features] [X]"

I almost never need to Enable All Features, and I'd rather not click [X] every time to close the bar.  Is there any way to automatically dismiss the infobar?

Answer (score 1):

Nope you can't, i personally avoid doing this to not seeing this kind of boxes, you could use alternatives than Adobe Reader XI like Sumatra PDF Reader as i use or Nitro PDF.

Answer (score -1):

Add the location you're trying to open it from to Adobe Reader's "Privileged Locations":

> You can add specific files, folders, and hosts to privileged locations to selectively trust PDF files, and bypass the security restrictions.

Under the Privileged Locations, do the following:

- To trust any sites you already trust in Internet Explorer, select Automatically Trust Sites From My Win OS Security Zones.
- To add only one or two PDFs from a location, click Add File.
- To create a trusted folder for multiple PDFs, click Add Folder Path or Add Host.
- To allow data to load from a website, enter the name of the root URL. For example, enter www.adobe.com, but not www.adobe.com/products. To trust files from secure connections only, select Secure Connections Only (https:).

[Source](http://helpx.adobe.com/reader/using/protected-mode-windows.html)

Comment: I don't want to trust the PDF and leave Protected Mode, though -- I'm just trying to get rid of the infobar, via hackish means if necessary.